# How to send images using an api with discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to create a simple discord bot which sends random pokemon names with their images with a specific command. I was successful in sending the image and name but only one is of them is sent.
This is the code that I am using

```
 var random= Math.floor( Math.random() * 800 ) <br> 
function getPoke() {<br>
 return fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/" + random)  
.then( res => {   <br>
    return res.json()   <br>
   }
)
<br>
   .then(data => {<br>
return data ["name"] +data["sprites"]["front_default"]<br>
   }
)
<br>
}
  if (msg.content === "$poke") {  <br>
    getPoke().then (pokemon=> msg.channel.send ( pokemon) );
```

If I only try with -

```
return data["sprites"]["front_default"]
```

It sends the image in the chat.
Please help

Comment: What is the issue? There doesn't seem to be a clear question.

Answer (score 1):

Doing

> return data["name"] +data["sprites"]["front_default"]

returns the name and the URL together, or combines them.

I think you would want to return the name and the URL with a space next to each other, so you would need a space in between them.

You can fix this by either doing `` return `${data.name} ${data.sprites.front_default}` ``  or  `return data.name + " " + data.sprites.front_default`.

Comment: Thanks. This is working but there's a slight problem it also returns the url of the image

Comment: @ArchitDandavate You can't get rid of that unless you download the image and attach it or make an embed for your message. I would recommend making an embed, and it also gives your image a nice look.

Comment: How do you use the embed image while using an api as for I normal message I can directly add the file parameter and forward the link

Comment: @ArchitDandavate I would add the image as a thumbnail to the embed. You can look at discord.js embeds here and here.